# how do you overload the UITableView "reloadData" method in a UITableViewController?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, reloaddata

how do you overload the UITableView "reloadData" method in a UITableViewController?

e.g. to put a log statement to see/confirm when reloadData is being called on each of my UITableViews

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just subclass the UITableView and override reloadData function:

**Header**

```
@interface MyUITableView : UITableView
```

**Function**

```
- (void)reloadData {
    [super reloadData];
    NSLog("Hello");
}
```

To use it you make instantiate `MyUITableView` instead of `UITableView`

Comment: This is the best way to do this.

Comment: so no why to achieve without subclassing?  also I was asking about is there a way to override within in my UITableViewController...so is the answer I have to create a custom subclass for UITableView, and then in my UITableViewController XIB make sure it's internal view points to my MyUITableView as opposed to UITableView?

Comment: Yes, you must change the class of the UITableView in interface builder if you use it.